# Basic integration by parts yields (seemingly?) wrong result

Tags: calculus, integration-by-parts

I'm trying to calculate a relatively trivial integral, but wolfram doesn't agree with me.

Here's my calculation:
\begin{align*}
\int \cos(2n\pi x)\cos(\pi x)dx &= \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) - \int \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) [-\pi \sin(\pi x)]dx \\[6px]
&= \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) + \frac1{2n} \int \sin(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)dx \\[6px]
&= \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) \\
&\qquad+ \frac1{2n} \left[ \frac1{2n\pi} \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)- \int \frac1{2n\pi} \cos(2n\pi x) \pi \cos(\pi x)dx\right] \\[6px]
&= \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) \\
&\qquad + \frac1{2n} \left[ \frac1{2n\pi} \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)- \frac1{2n}\int \cos(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x)dx\right] \\[6px]
&= \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) \\
&\qquad + \frac1{4n^2\pi} \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)- \frac1{4n^2}\int \cos(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x)dx
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
\left(1+\frac1{4n^2}\right)\int \cos(2n\pi x)\cos(\pi x)dx&= \frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) + \frac1{4n^2\pi} \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)\\[6px]
\int \cos(2n\pi x)\cos(\pi x)dx&= \frac{\frac1{2n\pi} \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) + \frac1{4n^2\pi} \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)}{\left(1+\frac1{4n^2}\right)} \\[6px]
\int \cos(2n\pi x)\cos(\pi x)dx&= \frac{2n \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) + \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)}{\pi\left(4n^2+1\right)}
\end{align*}
and here's what Wolfram thinks it should be:

[image]

Am I supposed to apply some goniometric identity here, or what's wrong in this calculation? Should I apply partial fractions perhaps?

Comment: Probably much easier if you write $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)$. Your formatting goes off the right on my monitor, set at fairly high pixels.

Comment: BTW, there can't still be a $dx$ on the right when you are done with an integral.

Comment: Or you can use the formula $$\cos a\cos b=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)\right)$$ which is even easier, I suppose, for some definition of "easier."

Comment: Why the downvote? I think he/she did a fair effort.

Comment: Formatting is terrible. @Pragabhava Can't read the right sides of lines 3-5 of the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's why seniors can edit. Anyway, it's everybody's right to downvote.

Comment: It would make this problem **much** easier to read if you first substituted $t=\pi x$. All those repeated $\pi$ invocations cloud this problem. Just solve $\int \cos(2nt)\cos(t)\,dt$ first, then divide the answer by $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no integration by parts substitution to get:

$$\int \sin(2\pi nx)\sin(\pi x) \,dx =\frac{1}{2\pi n}\cos(2\pi n x)\sin(\pi x)-\int\dots$$

(Step from line 2 to line 3.)

If you set $u=\sin(\pi x)$ and $dv=\sin(2\pi n x)$, then $v=-\frac{1}{2\pi n}\cos(2\pi n x)$. You don't have the minus sign in line $3$.

Indeed, both the signs are wrong in this step, so it should be:
$$\int \sin(2\pi nx)\sin(\pi x) \,dx =-\frac{1}{2\pi n}\cos(2\pi n x)\sin(\pi x)+\int\dots$$

This then leaves you with a $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ factor on the left, which gives you an $n^2-1$ denominator when you divide, which is close to what you want. You get:

$$\frac{2n \sin(2n\pi x) \cos(\pi x) - \cos(2n\pi x) \sin(\pi x)}{\pi\left(4n^2-1\right)}$$

This turns out to be equal to Wolfram Alpha's answer, I think. It takes some juggling with the $\sin(A+B)$ formula to see that:
$$(2n+1)\sin(2n-1)x +(2n-1)\sin(2n+1)x = 2(2n\sin(2n\pi x)\cos(\pi x)-\cos(2\pi n x)\sin(\pi x))$$

If you are allowed to not use integration by parts, it is easier to do this integral using:
$$\cos(A)\cos(B)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(A+B)-\cos(A-B)\right)$$